# Getting error in debugging my post.(Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped)

Tags: parsing

this is my website www.hackingsociety.in
actually i am getting a problem in sharing my website's post in facebook
yesterday only i got an error saying "Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped."
please help me out from here
"http://www.hackingsociety.in/2012/01/how-to-get-ip-address-of-any-user.html" => this URL I posted before also but that time it was working fine but don't know what all happend now.
please help me out as soon as possible.
i think it was a problem creatyed by me.
actually i was adding some meta tags for specific posts including their description.
but yesterday only when i tried sharing my post i found that post's thumbnail n description is not coming up while sharing so i decided to remove those newly made meta tags and so yestrday only i removed that but still not get that thing. my problem is still there.
please do check my html source code also.
please suggest me somethng with which i can get that all back again.
thanks